# Powershell search and replace to ignore lines that start with #

Tags: regex, powershell

I have a config file like this:

```
servername = 127.0.0.1
serverport = 44101
servername = 127.0.0.1
serverport = 0
#serverport = 44102
```

So far I have a function that replaces the port numbers:

```
# Replace Ports. Syntax:  Oldport=Newport
$WorkerPorts = @{44101=44201; 44102=44202; 44103=44203; 44104=44204}

function replacePort( $file, $Portarray )
{
  Write-Host "Replacing Ports in $file"

  foreach ($p in $Portarray.GetEnumerator())
  {
    Write-Host "  Replace Port $($p.Name) with $($p.Value) ... " -NoNewLine

    (Get-Content $file) | 
    Foreach-Object {$_ -replace $($p.Name), $($p.Value)} | 
    Set-Content $file

    Write-Host "Done"
  }
}

$DividerConf = "$strPath\divider\conf\divider.conf"
replacePort $DividerConf $WorkerPorts
```

However this also replaces the ports that are commented out (the lines that start with an #). How should the function look like to only replace the lines that don't start with a #? I was thinking about something like:

```
function replacePort( $file, $Portarray )
{
  Write-Host "Replacing Ports in $file"

  foreach ($p in $Portarray.GetEnumerator())
  {
    if ( $content -match "^[^#]*$($p.Name)*" )
    {
      Write-Host "  Replace Port $($p.Name) with $($p.Value) ... " -NoNewLine

      (Get-Content $file) | 
      Foreach-Object {$_ -replace $($p.Name), $($p.Value)} | 
      Set-Content $file

      Write-Host "Done"
    }
  }
}
```

but I can't figure out the correct regex.

**Edit**
Ok here's what I'm trying to do: Change the ports in my config File from

```
servername = 127.0.0.1
serverport = 44101
servername = 127.0.0.1
serverport = 0
#serverport = 44102
```

to

```
servername = 127.0.0.1
serverport = 44201
servername = 127.0.0.1
serverport = 0
#serverport = 44102
```

with a powershell function like above:

```
# Replace Ports. Syntax:  Oldport=Newport
$WorkerPorts = @{44101=44201; 44102=44202; 44103=44203; 44104=44204}
$DividerConf = "$strPath\divider\conf\divider.conf"

function replacePort( $file, $Portarray )
{
  #Here I need your help :)
}

replacePort $DividerConf $WorkerPorts
```

@Trevor: I usually show my solution so far. Otherwise I think it looks like I'm asking you to do my work ;)

Comment: Can you state your intent, of what you're trying to accomplish, rather than (or in addition to) providing a solution and asking for someone to hack it for you? There might be a much better way to accomplish whatever it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same as Trevor's but do the comment check on the way in.

```
Foreach ($line in (Get-Content -Path $configFile | Where {$_ -notmatch '^#.*'})) 
{ 
    Foreach ($Port in $PortMapping.Keys) 
    { ... }
}
```

And if you also want to skip any blank lines change the Where in the Get-Content to

```
Where { $_ -notmatch '^#.*' -and $_ -notmatch '^\s*$' }
```

Comment: This is how I do it too.  And you don't even need the .* in the regex.  Works fine for me with: Get-Content file.txt | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch "^#"}

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this would work, although it is certainly not the most efficient option either. Basically, you:

1. Iterate over every line of the `conf` file
2. For each line in the file, iterate over each port in the PortMapping
3. For each port in the PortMapping, perform the replacement, and then write the line to the destination file

**Code**

```
$PortMapping       = @{
                      44101 = 44201;
                      44102 = 44202;
                      44103 = 44203;
                      44104 = 44204;
                      };

$ConfigSource      = Get-Content -Path $PSScriptRoot\divider.conf;
$ConfigDestination = $PSScriptRoot\divider2.conf;

foreach ($Line in $ConfigFile) {
    if ($Line -notmatch '\#') {
        foreach ($Port in $PortMapping.Keys) {
            $Line = $Line.Replace($Port, $PortMapping[$Port]);
            Add-Content -Path $ConfigDestination -Value $Line;
        }
    }
}
```